# Setting Byte Order mark in WebTest in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, web-services

When invoking WCF WebService via **WebTest** in Visual Studio, I have set **stringbody** as raw Xml request, i.e. without this tag `<?xml version="1.0">` as below -

```
<Operation1Request xmlns="http://mycompany.com/myservice/operation1">
        <ChildElement1>
            Child Value
        </ChildElement1>
</Operation1Request>
```

It is the responsibility of Visual Studio to form the envelope and call **WCF Service**.

Do I have to set **byte order mark** explicitly, so that request could be formed in **utf-8**, or **utf-16**?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`

Does it make any difference for testing WCF Services?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is is a Rest or a Soap Service ?

From my point ov view, use a unit test for soap rather than web performance test. It will be easier to code and to maintain.

Comment: Hi Cybermaxs, This is SOAPService.